# JQuery 1.11.1 Deferred Then - multiple with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issued chaining a bunch of deferred 'then's in my javascript function.

In JQuery 1.7.2 I was able to create something like the following example, passing parameters from each one to determine if I continue.

```
myAjaxFunction(myParametersObject)
.done(function (noErrors) {
    if (anyErrors == true) {
        // call ajax routine

        return true; 
    } else {
        //stop code execution
        return false;
    }
})
.then(function (noErrors) {
    if (anyErrors == true) {
        // call ajax routine

        return true; 
    } else {
        //stop code execution
        return false;
    }
})
.then(function (noErrors) {
    if (anyErrors == true) {
        // call ajax routine

        return true; 
    } else {
        //stop code execution
        return false;
    }
})
.then(function (noErrors) {
    if (anyErrors == true) {
        // final code here

    }
});
```

It works perfectly on JQuery 1.7.2 but I am working on a project that requires JQuery 1.11.1 and this no longer works.

How can I pass parameters to the upcoming 'then' in JQuery 1.11.1?

Comment: `then` doesn't exist for jQuery 1.11.1. You might be able to use https://github.com/kriskowal/q and promisify the function which would allow you to use `.then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return jQuery promise value from `myAjaxFunction` appear to be defined as `noErrors` at `done` handler argument parameter

```
.done(function (noErrors) {
```

within `.done` handler as `anyErrors` ?

```
if (anyErrors == true) {
```

similarly at

```
.then(function (noErrors) {
    if (anyErrors == true) {
        // call ajax routine
```

?

Try setting same parameter as argument parameter and within handler , .e.g. `anyErrors`

---

```js
var dfd = $.Deferred().resolve(true);
dfd.done(function (anyErrors) {
    if (anyErrors == true) {
        // call ajax routine

        return true; 
    } else {
        //stop code execution
        return false;
    }
})
.then(function (anyErrors) {
    if (anyErrors == true) {
        // call ajax routine

        return true; 
    } else {
        //stop code execution
        return false;
    }
})
.then(function (anyErrors) {
    if (anyErrors == true) {
        // call ajax routine

        return true; 
    } else {
        //stop code execution
        return false;
    }
})
.then(function (anyErrors) {
    if (anyErrors == true) {
        // final code here
       document.body.textContent = anyErrors;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zr5rzb7v/1/

Comment: In my real code i was passing a json object that sometimes changes in a given 'then', and that was the problem. now if I pass a consistent object it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use it if you use first then and then done:

```
var request = $.ajax( url, { dataType: "json" } ),
  chained = request.then(function( data ) {
    return $.ajax( url2, { data: { user: data.userId } } );
  });

chained.done(function( data ) {
  // data retrieved from url2 as provided by the first request
});
```

See official jquery api documentation: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/#deferred-then-doneFilter-failFilter-progressFilter